# How to get mac address of a Linux and Unix system using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
lib.mac = function () {
var macAddress = undefined;
Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
    var alias = 0;
    ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
        if ('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal != false) {
            // skip over internal (i.e. 127.0.0.1) and non-ipv4 addresses
            return;
        }
        if (alias >= 1) {
            // this single interface has multiple ipv4 addresses
            macAddress = iface.mac;
        } else {
            // this interface has only one ipv4 adress
            macAddress = iface.mac;
        }
        ++alias;
    });
});
return macAddress;
```

}

Above is my code for windows system, and I don't know how to get mac-address for Linux and Unix system.

Answer (score 1):

> If you do not want to use a third-party service you can use `os` module

```
require("os").networkInterfaces()

{ lo:
   [ { address: '127.0.0.1',
       netmask: '255.0.0.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       internal: true,
       cidr: '127.0.0.1/8' },
     { address: '::1',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       scopeid: 0,
       internal: true,
       cidr: '::1/128' } ],
  enp0s31f6:
   [ { address: '172.22.100.113',
       netmask: '255.255.255.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '8c:16:45:f0:8f:51',
       internal: false,
       cidr: '172.22.100.113/24' },
     { address: 'fe80:fe23:adaa:583d:123c',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '8c:16:45:f0:8f:51',
       scopeid: 2,
       internal: false,
       cidr: 'fe80::4dd7:aeee:583d:7c7c/64' } ],
...
```

Comment: Is this code works for every OS (Linux & Unix as well)

Comment: Exactly I am running it from ubuntu linux, distribution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib [getmac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac).

Eg.:

```
// Fetch the computer's mac address
require('getmac').getMac(function(err, macAddress){
    if (err)  throw err
    console.log(macAddress)
});
```

Or just using the `os` module:

```
require("os").networkInterfaces();

{ lo:
   [ { address: '127.0.0.1',
       netmask: '255.0.0.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       internal: true,
       cidr: '127.0.0.1/8' },
     { address: '::1',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       scopeid: 0,
       internal: true,
       cidr: '::1/128' } ],
  enp2s0:
   [ { address: '192.168.1.10',
       netmask: '255.255.254.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '94:de:80:f0:ef:ef',
       internal: false,
       cidr: '192.168.4.144/23' },
     { address: 'fe80::ca45:44ac:89f4:85',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '94:de:80:f0:ef:ef',
       scopeid: 2,
       internal: false,
       cidr: 'fe80::ca45:44ac:89f4:85/64' }
   ],
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces

https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to use any lib, I want to write my own code

Comment: Ok. You can the use the `os` module.